# How to draw 3 circles on top of each other that are each transparent differently?

Tags: android, layer-list

[image]
I'm trying to create a layer of 3 circles that are all inner. And inside I will have a image of flowers.

The background can change...
If it sat on a blue background it will be blue shades. So I need to somehow adjust the transparrencies to make this work.
The center **MUST ALWAYS** be white completely though. I then want to add my image in the center.

I created a layer list to achieve this but I can't get the circles to be transparent and I can only get two circles to appear?
How would I get the bitmap to appear in the center?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Larger  circle in back -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#726"/>
            <size
                android:width="35dp"
                android:height="35dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#00f"/>
            <size
                android:width="25dp"
                android:height="25dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- Smaller  circle in front -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <!-- transparent stroke = larger_circle_size - smaller_circle_size -->
            <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent"
                android:width="5dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#f00"/>
            <size
                android:width="10dp"
                android:height="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#b5ed9259" />
            <size
                android:width="30dp"
                android:height="30dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <solid android:color="#cff27527" />
            <size
                android:width="25dp"
                android:height="25dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <solid android:color="#fbda5807" />
            <size
                android:width="20dp"
                android:height="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <size
                android:width="30dp"
                android:height="30dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_fav"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"/>

</layer-list>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: hey i see what your doing.  I did it another way. i made all the circles the same size. and then i just controlled the radius of the circle with the stroke width.  thanks for pointing me in the right direction.